# How to update feature class from feature layer with ArcPy Search and Update Cursor?

Tags: python, arcpy

I have a script where I select point features within a mile of major roads. If the feature falls within a mile of a major road then the field `within_mile_road` is updated with `yes`.  If not, it remains null.  I want to update the `within_mile_road` from the feature layers that I create back to the original feature class. How do I update the values that were written to the feature layer back to the feature class, here is my code below which does everything except update the original feature class.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = 'workspace'
    roads = 'roadsfc'
    fields = ['within_mile_road']
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc+"_lyr")
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc+"_lyr", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", roads, search_distance="1 Miles")
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc+"_lyr", fields) as cursor:
             for rowFL in cursor:
                rowFL[0] == 'yes'
                cursor.updateRow(rowFL)
```

Comment: Be extremely careful with the difference between comparison and assignment. Usually, the problem is the other direction.  Your indentation is also invalid.

Comment: A feature class is the data itself and a feature layer is a representation/view of this feature class. Once you update the layer, the source feature class gets updated as well. Am I missing a point?

Answer (score 1):

This is Another way which does not require layers and selections. Instead geometries are compared using the SHAPE@-token and the method distanceTo. For large datasets using Select by Location is likely much faster.

```
import arcpy

linefc = r"C:\data.gdb\lines"
pointfc = r"C:\data.gdb\points"
updatefield = 'Within'
maxdistance = 1600

linegeometries = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(linefc,'SHAPE@')]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pointfc,['SHAPE@',updatefield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if any(row[0].distanceTo(line) <= maxdistance for line in linegeometries):
            row[1]='Yes'
        else:
            row[1]='No'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: this is nice, what's the default unit of measure?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is whatever unit of the coordinate system, for example meters or degrees

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'workspace'
roads = r'roads'
fields = ['within_mile_road']
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc+"_lyr", where_clause = '''DATE_ > DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) AND DATE_<= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP''' )
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(fc+"_lyr", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", roads, search_distance="1 Miles")
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc+"_lyr", fields) as cursor:
         for rowFL in cursor:
            rowFL[0] ='YES'
            cursor.updateRow(rowFL)
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc+"_lyr",fields) as search_cur:
          for search_row in search_cur:
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as upd_cur:
               for upd_row in upd_cur:
                   if upd_row[0] == search_cur[0]:
                      upd_row[0] = search_row[0]
                      upd_cur.updateRow(upd_row)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields, where_clause = '''DATE_ > DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) AND DATE_<= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP''') as Ncursor:
         for rowNC in Ncursor:
            if rowNC[0] !='YES':
                rowNC[0] = 'NO'
                Ncursor.updateRow(rowNC)
```